# Move a range of numbered files?

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I've got 291 numbered files (starting at 001 - title and ending at 291 - title) that need moved into separate directories. (001 to 021 to folder 1, 022 to 053 to folder 2, they aren't necessarily the same number of files each time).

I figured I could do it in a yucky way like this: `ls | head -n 21 | sed -r 's|(.*)|mv \1 /path/to/folder1|' | sh`

I'm almost positive there's a better way, so what would it be?

EDIT: So that would've worked fine, but I remembered...

I'm not stuck using a terminal, so I used a file manager to click and drag. Question still stands though.

Comment: You want 21 subfolders in folder 1, and 22 folders in folder 2?

Comment: Have you reviewed unix.SE? There's a good thread on this here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/how-to-move-100-files-from-a-folder-containing-thousands

Comment: @DanielBeck no, I want the files to move to each folder. There are a different number of files going to each folder.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Lee That's pretty similar to what I was doing/have done before, I like it. Since the files match other files in another folder, I could `ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l` to get the numbers of lines.

Comment: @Rob Right. Still, different number of files into each directory. Automating that (including rules) is more effort than doing it yourself a few times.

Comment: It's easier to do 21, then 12, then 24, then 14, than it is to do that many individually.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you said it's not always exactly 21 files than you need to move the files manually, and to do that effectively you could use [**brace expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
mv filename{001..21} dir1
mv filename{022..53} dir2
...
```

Comment: This looks like it could work, I'll try it out.

Comment: This works perfectly, if you add a wildcard after the brackets. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: If the number is in the middle of the name, you can write `file{001..21}name`, you don't have to use wildcard. Anyway, happy it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will move the files as you described (except that the second range would be 022 to 042 for the second 21 files).

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 291; i++))
do
    ((d = (i - 1) / 21 + 1))
    printf -v file 'filename%03d' "$i"
    printf -v dir  'dirname%02d'  "$d"
    [[ -d "$d" ]] && mkdir "$d"
    mv "$f" "$d"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What I mean is to move a lot of files(like ten thousands or a million), shell will complain about the file list too long if you just use {1..20}, so

In *zsh*, you can load the *mv* builtin:

> setopt extended_glob zmodload
>
> zsh/files

after doing that, you can use command like:

```
mv ./somefolder/{1..100000}.txt  pathto/yourfolder/
```

or if you are writing some shell scripts, you can do something like this:

```
for i in `seq $start $end`;  
    do  mv "prefix${i}suffix.txt" pathto/yourfolder/  
done
```

if you are not using zsh, you may refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/solving-mv-argument-list-too-long

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.  Which answer are you referencing as the "more detailed answer"?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as OP wants to move different files to different directories.