# Move a range of files

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I have a range of numbered files (images) and I want to move them to subdirectory. [https://superuser.com/questions/380338/move-a-range-of-numbered-files#*=*](https://superuser.com/questions/380338/move-a-range-of-numbered-files#_=_) suggests that I use

`mv IMG_{001-022}.jpg subdir`

The problem is that considering that the number is a time stamp its not consecutive numbers. The above doesn't seem to work in my case.

Question is how would you do to the above in non-consecutive numbers.

Edit: Note in this particular case there are files numbered IMG_045.jpg for example. I only want any file that was between IMG_001-IMG_022

Comment: What do the file names actually look like?

Comment: added examples in edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move all files of the form `IMG_nnn.jpg` where `nnn` are three digits and not necessarily consecutive, use:

```
mv IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg subdir
```

To move only files numbered, say, from 001 to 0022, one can use:

```
mv IMG_{001..022}.jpg subdir
```

The problem with the above is that it will generate error messages for every file that does not exist.  The messages look like:

```
mv: cannot stat `IMG_014.jpg': No such file or directory
```

It is simple, though, to ignore those messages.  Use:

```
mv IMG_{001..022}.jpg subdir 2>&1 | grep -v "cannot stat"
```

Comment: Sorry added slightly more info in edit- I don't want anything above 022.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk Does the approach in the updated answer do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I would use xargs for this:

```
ls IMG_{001..022}.jpg 2&> /dev/null|xargs -I {} mv {} subdir/
```

Also, because I like to first test all of this before I use it, I would start by getting an `ls` command to print what you want. Once you have that perfect, just add the xargs part. I find this the best way to get it right every time.